# Send POST HTTP request from Google Sheets on data change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, sms

I am currently looking for a Google App Script that can POST a HTTP URL created using Row values within a google sheet whenever data in a particular column is modified or added. Ideally, the URL will be created using values of the Row where the cell was modified/added, with the purpose of sending SMS to users.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help CKE. In my scenario the Trigger is a new row added or modified. Action will be to POST a HTTP API using values of the Row, which was modified. Something like this: https://api.xyzabc.com/send/?message= hi . thanks for speaking to {Col H}. We have received your question {Col B}.&apiKey=5tR4eds/43f$edfrf443ffcv6t4e&numbers=&sender=ABCDEF
Payload Type: Form
Data: message, apiKey, numbers, sender-LIFSME
Wrap Request: no
Unflatten: yes

Comment: Sounds like you have a good handle on what needs doing. Review Google Apps Script class methods + triggers, and JavaScript syntax / concepts for the rest. Edit your question to include the script you manage to piece together, and highlight how you have attempted to resolve a specific remaining issue you have with it